# How to install Firefox Aurora from a terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, firefox, make

I want to install Firefox Aurora in Ubuntu 14.04 from the terminal (I know there are other ways) but I can't.

I've downloaded [`firefox-33.0a2.ca.linux-i686.tar.bz2`](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-aurora-l10n/firefox-33.0a2.ca.linux-i686.tar.bz2) (linked from [the download page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/all/)) and extracted it. But I don't know how to install it from the terminal. There is no `README` file.

I've read that I should use the following commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

It doesn't work, it throws me:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Also tried `chmod a+x configure` neither worked, it throws:

```
chmod: cannot access ‘configure’: No such file or directory
```

I can't find anything else about on the net. Running `./firefox`, as muru suggested, throws:

```
./firefox: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And that error is shown for `sudo ./firefox` as well.

This is a 64-bit Ubuntu system, and `libstdc++6` package is installed at version `4.8.2-19ubuntu1`. Purging and reinstalling the package doesn't make any difference to the problem.

Is there something that I'm missing? By the way, what about uninstalling it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The package doesn't need to be decompiled. You can just extract/open the tarball and doubleclick on 'firefox'. (This is a graphical based program).

Answer (score 2):

As [muru says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513040/how-to-install-firefox-aurora-from-a-terminal?noredirect=1#comment694192_513040), since you've downloaded a binary build of Firefox and not source code, running `./configure` and `make` commands does not apply to your situation. Instead, you run it with `./firefox` from the folder you unpacked.

This does not work now, but it should work nce you have the necessary libraries that Firefox. **The problem is that you have a 64-bit Ubuntu system (amd64), but you're attempting to run the 32-bit version of Firefox Aurora (i386).**

### If you *really* want to run 32-bit Aurora on 64-bit Ubuntu, you can:

Your 64-bit Ubuntu system *is* capable of running 32-bit executables, but most of them, including this one, require the 32-bit versions of some system libraries. Those versions are available for your 64-bit system, but they are not installed by default.

So, *if you really want to test the 32-bit version of Aurora on your 64-bit system*, you can install `libstdc++6` for the i386 architecture, by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++:i386
```

That should fix the error you're currently having, though you might instead get a similar error about another missing library. You could then fix that the same way, and eventually you'll have all the needed libraries installed.

To find out *what package* to install to get a particular file (in that case, it was `libstdc++.so.6`), you can use the [Ubuntu package database](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). In the textbox under "Search the contents of packages," put in the filename and click Search.

The search results [may look complicated at first](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libstdc%2B%2B.so.6&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any), but it's usually navigable if you keep in mind that 32-bit library .so files on a 64-bit Ubuntu system are usually stored in the `/usr/lib32` directory. In any case, feel free to expand your question if you have further difficulties.

### But I'd suggest you test 64-bit Aurora instead:

To get the 64-bit version of Firefox Aurora, download a snapshot archive with `x86_64` instead of `i386` in its name. In this case, you should use `firefox-33.0a2.ca.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2` instead of `firefox-33.0a2.ca.linux-i686.tar.bz2`.

You can get the 64-bit version by using a download link in the "Linux 64-bit" column of [the Aurora download page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/all/), instead of the "Linux" column which lists downloads for the 32-bit versions.

In this case, the file you probably want is:

- http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-aurora-l10n/firefox-33.0a2.ca.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

That's the current latest Aurora build for 64-bit Linux in the Catalan language. But note that in the future, there will be a later version (so in the future, that link should serve only as an example of what the URL looks like, rather than being the best download).

Comment: Amazing! I'll try this asap and report the result. I hope this will work. Thanks for your time and patience helping me!